# using the correct to_chars overload

Tags: c++, c++17, clang, apple-m1

I'm using Clang 14 (on Apple M1), which has full support for C++ 17, and I'm trying to utilize the new [to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) function. Here's my very simple test file:

```cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char a[10];
  double pi = 3.141592;

  std::to_chars_result res = std::to_chars(a, a+10, pi);
  *res.ptr = '\0';
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

My compile command is `clang -std=c++17 test_to_chars.cpp`, and the output is below:

```
test_to_chars.cpp:8:30: error: call to deleted function 'to_chars'
  std::to_chars_result res = std::to_chars(a, a+10, pi);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:166:6: note: candidate function has been explicitly deleted
void to_chars(char*, char*, bool, int = 10) = delete;
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:450:1: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_integral<double>::value' was not satisfied [with _Tp = double]
to_chars(char* __first, char* __last, _Tp __value)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:458:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
to_chars(char* __first, char* __last, _Tp __value, int __base)
^
test_to_chars.cpp:8:24: error: no viable conversion from 'void' to 'std::to_chars_result'
  std::to_chars_result res = std::to_chars(a, a+10, pi);
                       ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:154:25: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'const std::to_chars_result &' for 1st argument
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS to_chars_result
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:154:25: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'std::to_chars_result &&' for 1st argument
2 errors generated.
```

I'm calling `to_chars(char*, char*, double)` but for some reason it's using an implicit conversion and trying to call `to_chars(char*, char*, bool, int = 10)` instead, which is a deleted function.

Is there a way for me to tell C++ that I don't want it to convert my double parameter to a bool?

Comment: Clang does not support `<charconv>` for floating points.

Comment: It looks like your compiler doesn't yet support the floating-point version of `std::to_chars`.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17 (Under "Elementary string conversions") libc++ 14 supports floating point to_chars. Check if `_LIBCPP_VERSION >= 14000`

Comment: @Artyer since he runs on Apple M1, he probably has Apple Clang that has no support to `to_chars` for floating points even in version 14.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know Clang and Apple Clang were different things. @AlX23z where did you read that `to_chars` is not supported? @Artyer yep, `_LIBCPP_VERSION` is 13000.

Comment: I guess there it is in the docs: https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx17.html#note-p0067. I just wasn't expecting to have Clang 14 with libc++ 13. I thought the version numbers would match up.

Comment: Clang 14 supports only `to_chars` but not `from_chars` for floating points. See the reference linked by Artyer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using Clang 14 (on Apple M1), which has full support for C++ 17

This is unfortunately not correct. While the compiler itself has full C++17 support, the stdlib of your clang version (Apple clang 14) does not implement any floating point charconv features.

See the entry "Elementary string conversions" in the [cppreference table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features).

It is important to note that you are not running "clang 14", but "Apple clang 14". Your code snippet [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/qW6K5Tjer) on normal clang 14.